# Ocultar datos de una tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen día, como hago para que al abrir el siguiente programa y a la hora de hacer cualquier busqueda  no me salgan los datos que tengo almacenados en la tabla que tengo en mysql. 
Este es el programa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de dicho programa:

Con esta parte se crean los input y la tabla donde se van a almacenar los datos buscados:

```
 <title>busqueda</title>
 <p>
 <form name="form1" method="POST" action="busqueda.php" id="cdr">
 <h2>Buscar Usuario</h2>
 <input name="busca" type="text" id="busqueda" placeholder="Ingrese el día">
 <input name="mes" type="text" id="mesqueda" placeholder="Ingrese el mes">
 <input name="año" type="text" id="añoqueda" placeholder="Ingrese el año">
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buscar"> 
 </p>
 </form>

 <table width="500" border="1" id="tab">
 <tr>
 <td width="60">Día</td>
 <td width="90">Mes</td>
 <td width="90">Año</td>
 </tr>
```

Esta es la parte del codigo con que se enlaza php y mysql y con el que se realiza la busqueda a la base de datos:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 $busca="";
 $mes="";
 $año="";
 $busca=$_POST['busca'];
 $mes=$_POST['mes'];
 $año=$_POST['año'];
 $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
 mysqli_select_db($con,"tutorial");
 if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo "no conectado";
}
$con->real_query("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia like '%$busca%' and mes LIKE '%$mes%' and anio like '%$año%'");
$resultado= $con->use_result();

?>
```

Y esta es la parte del código php que incrusta dichos resultados de la busqueda en la tabla:

```
 <?php
while($muestra=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td>'.$muestra['dia'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$muestra['mes'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$muestra['anio'].'</td>'; 
echo'</tr>';
 }

 ?>
 </table>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda !!

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que quitar esta parte de código ya que el fetch_assoc  recupera una fila de resultados como un array asociativo,por lo que mientras se encuentren filas en tu base de datos te ira mostrando los campos día,mes y año.

```
<?php
while($muestra=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td>'.$muestra['dia'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$muestra['mes'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$muestra['anio'].'</td>'; 
echo'</tr>';
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea la respuesta correcta, me parece que lo que quiere es que si se muestre la información pero que no sea legible, algo como las contraseñas que no se ven (enmascaramiento de datos), yo también ando en búsqueda de algo similar para enmascarar los datos y amenos que se entre con el usuario correcto que los datos se puedan ver, algo así como una capa mas de seguridad. En este momento se me ocurre que pudiera usar en lugar de un input de tipo texto uno de tipo password, pero el problemita seria en la información de las tablas a menos que encripte campo por campo lo cual me llevaría a pensar que ocuparía tiempo de procesador. Vaya parece que esa es la solución a menos que alguien mas sepa como hacerlo.

Comment: Pero para este caso, no necesitas hacer nada extraordinario, los resultados directamente los pueden mostrar como asteriscos, duros y puros, una cantidad fija de asteriscos y listo, y en caso que si sea el usuario que deba ver los datos, que te los muestre de la base tal cual.

Answer (score 0):

la verdad es que no tiene mucho sentido buscar algo, y no mostrarlo, de todas formas, si es el requerimiento, PHP dispone de muchisimas funciones de String muy potentes, en este caso te podría servir STR_REPEAT, que lo que hace es repetir el caracter que le pases como primer parametro, la cantidad de veces que le indiques en el segundo parámetro.

Entonces, para cada resultado de tu base, debes quitar la longitud de esa cadena con SRTLEN y el caracter que quieras usar para ocultar el texto real.

```
<?php
while($muestra=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
  echo'<tr>';
  echo'<td>'.str_repeat("*", strlen($muestra['dia'])).'</td>';
  echo'<td>'.str_repeat("*", strlen($muestra['mes'])).'</td>';
  echo'<td>'.str_repeat("*", strlen($muestra['anio'])).'</td>'; 
  echo'</tr>';
 }

 ?>
```